# NSAttributedString from HTML with Hyperlinks

Tags: html, swift, hyperlink, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I am attempting to render a large HTML string, that contains hyperlinks, into a UITextView using NSAttributedString. Everything is working fine except the hyperlinks, they don't actually open the link.

For an example, here is a dummy version of my html string:

```
let htmlString = "<html><p>If you would like to contact someone, you can email 
them at <a class=rvts10 href=\"mailto:some@one.com\">some@one.com</a></p></html>"
```

I have a function called `convertHTML()` that converts strings to NSAttributedString with html document type options, that I use to assign to the UITextView's attributed text:

```
textView.attributedText = htmlString.convertHTML()
```

The TextField is `selectable` but not `editable`. When the page is loaded, you can see the hyperlink styling (blue text) and everything, but you can't tap on the link and open the mail app.

I assume this I need to change "mailto:..." to something else that iOS will recognize, but I just have no idea what needs to be done to allow this link to be linkable.

---

This is my html method:

```
func convertHtml() -> NSAttributedString{
    guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
    do{
        return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
    }catch{
        return NSAttributedString()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have error  with your convertHTML() Method check this

```
 let htmlString = "<html><p>If you would like to contact someone, you can email them at <a class=rvts10 href=\"mailto:some@one.com\">some@one.com</a></p></html>"

            // you have to convert string to data
            let data = Data(htmlString.utf8)
            // then convert data to NSAttributedString with NSAttributedString.DocumentType.htm
            if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
                self.textView.attributedText = attributedString
            }
```

Comment: I just pasted my convertHTML() method below, I don't think it's wrong.. I am getting a message `Filtering mail sheet account for bundle ID:` error when I click the link however..

Comment: Are you test on simulator , Are your problem is that Link not be clickable , or when you click nothing happen

Comment: I am using a simulator. Turns out that that weblink work fine, but email links are not. Everything is clickable, but the emails are not actually opening up the mail app. Weblinks are being opened in the default web browser however

Answer (score -1):

I use this extension :

```
import Foundation

    extension NSAttributedString {

        convenience init(htmlString html: String) throws {
            try self.init(data: Data(html.utf8), options: [
                .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
                ], documentAttributes: nil)
        }

    }
```

After implementing you can use it like this:

```
contentTextField.attributedText = try? NSAttributedString(htmlString: aHTMLString)
```

Comment: thats literally no different than what I have

Comment: yes it is, en extension is a better way to implement this kind of function, regard ;-)

Comment: My function is in an extension of the string class. You extended the Attributed string class to add an initialize, I extended the String class to add a function. Neither one is better than the other. They provide the same functionality.